# What is the relation between Time and Energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, time, mass-energy

According to the formula $E = hf$, it can be re-arranged like $E = h/t$ where, $t =$ time, $E =$ energy, and $h =$ Planck's Constant. So from this, it would be reasonable to derive a relationship between time and energy that is, **Energy is inversely proportional to time**. Also, $E = mc^2$ where $m =$ mass, so **mass is inversely proportional to time**. Keep this relationship in mind and let's move forward.

As we approach the speed of light mass increases due to the increase in kinetic energy and time slows down. But this slowing of time from the perspective of a stationary observer, observing this object approaching the speed of light seems to take more time to cross two points in space as viewed by the observer's clock. So when we say time slowed down, it actually means that the passing rate of time has been decreased that is for a stationary observer time passes by **1 hour/hour** but the time for objects seems to pass by (let's assume) **30 min/hour**.

So is from the relationship of mass, energy and time as discovered from above means that, **as the mass or energy increases the rate at which time passes by decreases**.

But I am confused whether it is true or I haven't considered some factors?

Comment: The relation $$E=hf$$ is a formula specifically for the energy carried by a photon. The photon frequency relates not to time in general but to the *time period*: $$f=\frac 1T.$$ So your initial point doesn't directly show a relation between energy and time, but rather between photon energy and the duration of a photon wave.

Comment: Exactly, plus $E=mc^2$ can only indirectly be applied to the massless photons: when two massive objects such as an electron and positron react and generate photons.

Comment: This question reminds me of [this](https://64.media.tumblr.com/9449866466b7b70928a8678ca0c110b6/75f9f346bce88812-43/s500x750/4f276e5b42909eaccba03651684686584ef98be3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The relation between time and energy is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, namely
\begin{equation}
\Delta E \Delta t \propto h
\end{equation}
It says roughly speaking that if you attempt to measure a time period with $\Delta t$ accuracy, you can't tell with arbitrary accuracy that, for example, the energy of the system is 0. If you measure firstly the energy and secondly the time duration of the system, and then the converse, you will end up with two different couples of results.

Also, relativistic mass is an outdated and unpopular concept, so mass is invariant as speed changes. It is in fact the measure of the energy that depends on the referential, not the mass.